# Как тексту со спец символами присвоить переменную так чтобы не было ошибок

Tags: python

Мне нужно присвоить переменную данному тексту:

```
{
    game    "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"
    title   "COUNTER-STRIKE'"
    title2  "GO"
    type multiplayer_only
    nomodels 1
    nohimodel 1
    nocrosshair 0
    bots 1
    hidden_maps
    {
        "test_speakers"     1
        "test_hardware"     1
    }
    nodegraph 0
    SupportsXbox360 1
    SupportsDX8 0
    GameData    "csgo.fgd"


    FileSystem
    {
        SteamAppId              730     // This will mount all the GCFs we need (240=CS:S, 220=HL2).
        ToolsAppId              211     // Tools will load this (ie: source SDK caches) to get things like materials\debug, materials\editor, etc.
        
        //
        // The code that loads this file automatically does a few things here:
        //
        // 1. For each "Game" search path, it adds a "GameBin" path, in <dir>\bin
        // 2. For each "Game" search path, it adds another "Game" path in front of it with _<langage> at the end.
        //    For example: c:\hl2\cstrike on a french machine would get a c:\hl2\cstrike_french path added to it.
        // 3. For the first "Game" search path, it adds a search path called "MOD".
        // 4. For the first "Game" search path, it adds a search path called "DEFAULT_WRITE_PATH".
        //

        //
        // Search paths are relative to the base directory, which is where hl2.exe is found.
        //
        // |gameinfo_path| points at the directory where gameinfo.txt is.
        // We always want to mount that directory relative to gameinfo.txt, so
        // people can mount stuff in c:\mymod, and the main game resources are in
        // someplace like c:\program files\valve\steam\steamapps\<username>\half-life 2.
        //
        SearchPaths
        {
            Game                |gameinfo_path|.
            Game                csgo
        }
    }
}
```

при попытке присвоения выдает ошибку Неверный синтакс. Как экранировать все спец символы в этом тексте?

Comment: Зачем их экранировать, заверните строку в тройные кавычки `'''` да и всё

Comment: Присвиивают не переменную чему-то, а что-то переменной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не экранировать текст со спец символами и ковычками достаточно поместить его в тройные ковычки а также поставить букву r, вот пример

````
print(r```Пример текста```)
````